# How to deserialize where keys are numbers

Tags: c#, json

Any thoughts on how to create the C# class for how to deserialise this correctly?

```
{
      "key": "MobileNetworkOperator",
      "name": "MNO Option",
      "type": "n",
      "options": [
        {
          "0": "Spark LTE M1"
        },
        {
          "1": "Default"
        },
        {
          "2": "AT&T"
        },
        {
          "3": "Verizon"
        },
        {
          "4": "Telstra"
        },
        {
          "5": "T-Mobile USA"
        },
        {
          "6": "China Telecom"
        },
        {
          "7": "Sprint"
        },
        {
          "8": "Vodafone"
        },
        {
          "9": "Telus"
        },
        {
          "10": "Deutsche Telecom"
        },
        {
          "11": "Standard Europe"
        }
      ],
      "rebootRequired": true,
      "default": 0
    },
```

json2csharp.com gives the classes below but it does not seem to work.  After deserialise, the right number of options items are present but all fields in each Option are set to null.  I presume because the members are called '_0' instead of the actual '0' in the JSON???

```
   public class Option
    {
        public string _0 { get; set; }
        public string _1 { get; set; }
        public string _2 { get; set; }
        public string _3 { get; set; }
        public string _4 { get; set; }
        public string _5 { get; set; }
        public string _6 { get; set; }
        public string _7 { get; set; }
        public string _8 { get; set; }
        public string _9 { get; set; }
        public string _10 { get; set; }
        public string _11 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public List<Option> options { get; set; }
        public bool rebootRequired { get; set; }
        public int @default { get; set; }
    }
```

Note that this is part of a larger object with many of these items in which there can be no or many options in each item, but I tried to simplify it down.

I am using the System.Text.Json parser.  Thanks in advance for your advice.  This is my first go at JSON in C#!

Comment: Use [this site](https://json2csharp.com/) to convert your model. Make sure to check the `Use JsonPropertyName (.NET Core)` or `Add JsonProperty Attributes` (for Newtonsoft.Json) checkbox.

Comment: nevermind -- i see now the amount of items can vary. You won't be able to create a concrete model to represent that. You'll have to do some fancy-dancy custom deserialization.

Comment: I like enums in this case. public enum Options { SparkLteM1 = 0, ATandT = 1, ... } And if I need a readable name I set a [Description(...)] attribute on top of each item. Or you create your own attrubite. [ EDIT ] Or is this just a list of options and the number is the auto increment index?

Comment: make Options a `Dictionary`

Comment: @FranzGleichmann -- it's an array.

Comment: Make dictionary a `List<Dictionary>` then flattern it with `x.Options.SelectMany(trd=> trd).ToDictionary(kvp=> kvp.Key, kvp=> kvp.Value)`

Comment: What are you using? `System.Text.Json`? or `Newtonsoft.Json`. You need to be explicit. There are major differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deserializing a JSon I will always go for a class representing exactly the json structure/

Class definition using System.Text.Json:

```
public partial class JsonDto
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> options { get; set; }
    public bool rebootRequired { get; set; }
    public long @default { get; set; }
}
```

Class definition using Newtonsoft.Json, is the same. Json property in order to have capitilized properties.

```
public partial class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("options")]
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Options { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rebootRequired")]
    public bool RebootRequired { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("default")]
    public long Default { get; set; }
}
```

The deserialization is almost the same

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDto>(input); // Newtonsoft.Json
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonDto>(input);
```

Then a simple transpormation where we ger rid of the extra list in `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`.

```
var result = 
    new UsableObject {
        Key=jsonDto.key,
        Name=jsonDto.name,
        Type=jsonDto.type,
        RebootRequired=jsonDto.rebootRequired,
        Default=jsonDto.@default,
        Options=jsonDto.options
                        .SelectMany(trd=> trd)
                        .ToDictionary(kvp=> kvp.Key, kvp=> kvp.Value),
    };
```

Live demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/c9rNL0

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This was exactly what I needed.  I had tried public <Dictionary<string, string>> options and variations of arrays of dictionaries.  But I hadn't tried a list.  I sort of knew what I wanted but couldn't quite get there!

Answer (score 2):

OP stated that they are using `System.Text.Json` as their parser. So, with that being known, we will need to create a custom `JsonConverter`.

Start by creating an `Option` class:

```
public class Option
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Next, create our `JsonConverter` implementation based on the `Option` object from above:

```
public class MyOptionConverter : JsonConverter<Option>
{
    public override Option Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        reader.Read(); // read in the first token
        var key = int.Parse(reader.GetString()); // get the value as an integer
        reader.Read(); // read in the next token
        var value = reader.GetString(); // get the value as string
        reader.Read(); // read in End-of-object
        return new Option { Key = key, Value = value }; // return our new object
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer, Option value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // we aren't going to handle writing for now.
    }
}
```

Let's create a model that represents your data:

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonPropertyName("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("options")]
    public IReadOnlyList<Option> Options { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("rebootRequired")]
    public bool RebootRequired { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("default")]
    public int Default { get; set; }
}
```

Then to deserialize, you would simply do this:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new MyOptionConverter());

var myObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(theJson, options);
```

### Edited To Add:

@Llama brought it to my attention (in the comments) that OP is probably using `Newtonsoft` and not `System.Text.Json`.

Someone already posted the `Newtonsoft` solution, but the author deleted it even though it was probably the correct answer.

I am going to leave this answer up just in case it may help someone else.

Comment: Note that OP is using JSON.NET.

Comment: She said "built in" -- Newtonsoft isn't built in.

Comment: Perhaps OP is using pre-3.0 .NET Core, where it was indeed built-in as the default serializer for ASP.NET Core, or perhaps OP is just mistaken about it being built in. Either way, OP said: _"I am using the built in .net `JsonConvert` class. "_ and that certainly doesn't exist in System.Text.Json.

Comment: well, some other dude posted the Newtonsoft solution. but deleted it. What a bummer.

Comment: Well, I'm voting to undelete that answer. Both answers are useful for other people encountering the same issue, since some might be using JSON.NET and some might be using System.Text.Json, so they should probably both be here.

Comment: I don't have that permission yet. I guess i will leave mine up. hopefully it doesn't get downvoted.

Comment: Hopefully not. :)

Comment: Sorry, it seems I caused some confusion when posting about which parsing library I am using.  I don't know what the underlying library is, I didn't realise there were many options.  I used a NuGet package System.Text.Json and  in the code 'using System.Text.Json'.

Comment: @AshleyDuncan -- OK -- this answer should work for you then.